# idiomatic way to reduce code replication in c#

Tags: c#, templates, generics, design-patterns

I am new in C# (I come from C++), and I faced a simple pattern that in C++ I would resolve using templates, but the same approach does not work using C# generics.

The next code (a mix of C# with C++ templates) shows my problem.

```
class A { /* ... */ }
class B { /* ... */ }
// C, D, ...

class W
{
    public void Update(A a) { /* ... */ }
    public void Update(B b) { /* ... */ }
    // C, D, ...
}

class X
{
    template <typename T>
    public void Update(IEnumerable<T> vs) {
        if (vs.any(vs => CreateOrUpdate(v))) {
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    public void Update(T v)
    {
        if (CreateOrUpdate(v)) {
            doStuff()
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    private bool CreateOrUpdate(T v)
    {
        W w;
        bool updated = false;
        if (!m.TryGetValue(v.Id, out w)) {
            w = new W(v.Id);
            m.Add(w.Id, w);
            updated = true;
        }
        return w.Update(v) || updated;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, W> m;
}
```

Even if `A, B, ...` implement a interface like `interface IId { string Id { get; } }` and I use generics `public void Update<T>(IEnumerable<T> vs) : where T : IId`, the code wouldn't work due `w.Update(v)` (it would require add `public bool Update(IId id)` in `W`, but then this method would be the one that is always called).

I understand the difference between C# generics and C++ templates from a theoretical point of view, and why `w.Update(v)` cannot statically dispatch the call among `Update` method from `W`. However, I cannot figure out which is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Please tag the question appropriate - is it a C# question?

Comment: Yes. Actually, it's tagged as c#. (I don't know what you mean).

Comment: Is it C++? if not, remove the tag.

Comment: What do you mean by: _but then this method would be the one that is always called_?

Comment: But if you want to reduce code duplication, shouldn't you actually *prefer* to have a single `Update(IId id)` method in `W`? Or `Update<T>(T id) where T : IId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is indeed to add a method `public bool Update(IId id)` to class `W`, but you need to dynamically dispatch the argument `id`:

```
class W
{
    public bool Update(IId id)
    {
        dynamic d_id = id;
        return Update(d_id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The program will determine at runtime which of the `Update` functions to call, because `d_id` is declared `dynamic`.

If you add another class `E` that implements `IId`, but forget to implement `Update(E e)`, the above `Update` function will recursively call itsself until you’re out of memory. You can avoid the danger of infinite recursion by renaming `Update(IId id)` to `DoUpdate(IId id)` and call `DoUpdate` in `CreateOrUpdate`. You will then get a meaningful exception stating that `id` of type `E` cannot be dispatched.

There is a nice [blog post on multimethods in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laurionb/archive/2009/08/13/multimethods-in-c-4-0-with-dynamic.aspx) on MSDN that might help you.

Comment: Thank you. I thought in a similar solution using polymorphism, but not as elegant as yours. I assume that there's no way to do that avoiding runtime checking, am I right?

Comment: You can implement the visitor pattern, as [Max has pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23886361/1231686). IMHO, the visitor pattern isn’t elegant at all, though, since it’s just an intrusive way to implement dynamic dispatch manually.

Comment: This was the solution I came up, but as you said, in my case A, B... don't should know about W. Sorry, can you confirm that there's no solution without runtime checking?

Comment: Resolving this at runtime is similar to casting, you have no idea if it will work until you actually run your app and you risk getting a run time exception (or even worse, a stack overflow in this case). I would avoid this, as you lose type safety, and it really indicates a code smell.

Comment: @Groo, what alternative I have? If I want the code to be type safe avoiding code duplication I can just add "public void W::Update(A a) { genericUpdate(a); }", and make genericUpdate private.

Comment: @user3679024 A common alternative is double dispatch, which happens at runtime as well. It is a matter of personal taste which of the approaches you prefer: intrusive, but type-safe versus non-intrusive, but less type-safe. Search the web for “visitor pattern multimethods”, there is a lot of dispute to be found. The use of either doesn’t indicate a code smell (@Groo), but a lack of expressiveness of C#.

Comment: @user3679024: are you sure that you need to duplicate these methods at all? Can you describe what are they doing? If you need to add a new method for each subtype (`Update(A a)`, `Update(B b)`) then you are surely doing unnecessary plumbing, especially if they are all merely calling a common private method.

Comment: @Lumen: why is your choice to use `dynamic` or casting "lack of expressiveness of C#"? Lack compared to what? OP is coming from a C++ background, and there are no `dynamic` variables there. And double dispatch is not the same as casting or dynamic binding, because it's still type safe. And yet it's still a [code smell](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/04/19/double-dispatch-is-a-code-smell/), breaking the S & O in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: The problem is that you are assuming that the solution to OPs problem are multimethods, while they already indicate a potential design issue.

Comment: @Groo I’m saying that C# and many other programming languages lack multi-methods or multiple dispatch – unfortunately, because there exist many applications where multi-methods are desirable and very expressive (e.g. AST manipulation). Whether or not multi-methods are suitable in the OP’s case can hardly be judged from `A,B,C,D,…,W,X` with zero semantics. And while it’s certainly true that the OP might have designed his code poorly, we shouldn’t argue about code that we don’t know.

Comment: @Groo, they are doing nothing but calling to `X::genericUpdate`, which are the same methods than the `X::Update` from the code of my question. In this way I can ensure that the public interface is type safe (i.e `W::Update(c)` would not compile if `c` is an object of `class C : IId` - a user could create such class C - such that `W` don't implement `DoUpdate(C c)`). How would you resolve this problem otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better answer but here's my take.

Let's say both `A` and `B` implement the interface `IId` with the property `Id` in it. I would add a method `Update(W w)` in the interface to be implemented in these classes, that way you would write:

```
private bool CreateOrUpdate(T v)
{
    W w;
    bool updated = false;
    if (!m.TryGetValue(v.Id, out w)) {
        w = new W(v.Id);
        m.Add(w.Id, w);
        updated = true;
    }
    return v.Update(w) || updated;
}
```

That way you would treat each case the same which is basically the point of interfaces (instead of toying with `typeof` switches and bad performance reflection). In my opinion this is a better OOP approach to your problem. This is known as [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

By the way, you can write:

```
 class X<T> where T : IId
```

Instead of writing generic methods (your class becomes generic instead of its methods). It has to make sense semantically therefore I can't really tell for your specific case (the classes name being obfuscated).

Comment: The body of `Update(W w)` would be `w.Update(this)`, I assume? So your approach is generally known as the visitor or double dispatch pattern which is a way to manually implement dynamic dispatch (granted, in a type-safe way).

Comment: Yes you can either do that or write the logic within classes that implement the interface ; it really depends on the case. Both approaches can be justified I would say :)

Comment: I agree. I tend to use both patterns on occasion.